# Pushviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have an tabbar but i want to switch to another view on a tap so i did

```
UIViewController *controller;
switch (item.tag) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"1");


        controller = [[2012ViewController alloc] init]; 

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller
                                             animated:YES];

        break;
```

But when i tap it it goes to 2012ViewController (the 'homepage') but a back button appears. But it needs to go to the 2012ViewController without showing the backbutton cause when i click on the back button on the 2012ViewController screens it's

2012ViewController > (back button) 'The screen where i tapped the back button' > (back button) 2012ViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your problem you should simply call

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will pop your view controller from the navigation controller stack. This way you'll come back to the first view controller instead of pushing a new one.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the problem i need to go back to an specific viewcontroller with this line of code i'm going one viewcontroller back. But when (first viewcontroller > second > third (on the third viewcontroller i tap on the homepage button (first viewcontroller) it need's to breng me there)

Comment: Use instead `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]`. This will bring you to the first controller.